# Disk space allocated for system volume

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have just bought a laptop with 1000 GB SSD disk and the laptop came up with preinstalled Windows 10 operating system. What I am trying to do now is to divide the disk into two volumes with the Disk manager usage.

My idea was that the first volume (lets say System) should be occupied by the operating system itself and the antivirus software and the second volume (lets say Data) should be occupied by software which I need for my work (i.e. Matlab, Netbeans IDE, MPLABX IDE, TexLive, Cygwin, Doxygen and Python) and associated files.

I have been struggling with how much space shall I dedicate for the System volume. I have found that the Windows 10 need at least 32 GB (recommended value is 40 GB) and the antivirus software which I have been using consumes 77 MB. Does anybody have any rule of thumb how much space should be dedicated for the System volume? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Outside of making it easier to backup your system drive, there is no performance gain from installing software on separate partitions, you should provide at least the amount of space required by Windows (specified by Microsoft).

Comment: Some installers will let you choose the destination folder, but some will default to C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files(x86) .  Some poorly-coded programs will break, and not always obviously, when not installed to the default locations.  It's OK to have a Data partition and a Programs/System partition , but I don't suggest having a System partition and an Everything Else partition.